# Scripts aren't working on certain pages in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, wordpress

My scripts are working on the some pages in Wordpress; on other pages, some of them stop working.

For example.

In the working page, if you go to the diamond menu, click search, then close it, everything functions as it should (the search menu is visible:hidden).

but if you go to the not working example, the search menu is still visible (although opacity: 0) and you can't click anything.

Other scripts are acting up as well on the non working pages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw console error on the page where things not working.

```
document.getElementById("homenav") is null
```

[image]